# Low Variables: must new variable be entered in CP?

Tags: low-variables

I just started using Low-Variables as a Snippet replacement (among other uses of course) because I need Snippets to be saved as files.

Now I am wondering if a new Low-Variable always has to be entered through the CP or not. It looks like it to me but I was hoping to have some standard variables for different projects that I could just throw in and be ready to go.

Thanks and Cheers,

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a new LV must be created through the CP. A new file will not create a new variable. Why? Check out these replies:

- https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/dealing_with_low_variable_files_in_a_git_workflow#reply_11414674
- https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/files_are_not_synched_back_to_ee#reply_10217404

Comment: Thanks, I figured that it must be because of the reasons given in the two links (which I unfortunately couldn't find myself... :-()